# How to solve this "LocalProcessingException was unhandled by user code"?

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

An error occurred during local report processing.

```
Dim params(2) As ReportParameter
params(0) = New ReportParameter("CallClassCode", callClassCode)
params(1) = New ReportParameter("DateTimeFrom", startDateTime)
params(2) = New ReportParameter("DateTimeTo", endDateTime)
rvScreen.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
rvScreen.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

`rvScreen.LocalReport.Refresh()` is highlighted and the error message was:

> LocalProcessingException was unhandled by user.

An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: You are creating an array of 2, and trying to store 3 elements in it!

Comment: I've tried to change it into 3. But still, same error.

Comment: You can use a `Try/Catch` block and give a look at `InnerException.Message` for more informations about the problem. Maybe you doesn't set your `LocalReport.ReportPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that ReportViewer is not empty:

[image]

Fill the `Report Data Source` and `Report Data Instance` fields.

ReportViewer

1- choose ReportViewer Task

2- Choose Data Source

3- fill Report Data Source

4- fill Report Data Instance